# illustrative book of differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology

I look for a book of differential geometry which emphasizes the illustration of the modern basic concepts and theorems and their "geometric aspects" (such as smooth manifolds, differential forms, coordinatefree Integration, orientation, geodesics, Riemannian metrics, curvature,...) to examples rather than developing new concepts and theorems. Especially (counter)examples who may motivated the modern basics are my key interest.

If you know some algebraic geometry literature, I look for a similar book as "Geometry of Schemes" by Eisenbud and Harris but now for differential geometry.

Comment: Try Mishchenko, Fomenko "A course of differential geometry and topology" with lot of great pictures by Fomenko (he's the guy who trolls the world history), some non-rigorous proofs (like cut here, move there...). I personally don't like the book because of the coordinate approach almost everywhere. But when I started learning differential geometry, the book (in Russian edition) provides me intuitive understanding for many things.

Comment: Try Berger’s A Panoramic View of Riemannian Geometry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try these:

> Differential Geometry - Clifford Taubes
>
> Introduction to Smooth Manifolds - John Lee

these two are my favorite.

Comment: another good reference is: Geometry, Topology and Physics, by Nakahara.